# Why are these diodes on the row inputs of this matrix keyboard with column pull-ups?

Tags: keyboard, matrix

The following is the keypad circuit of a NEC TK-85 8085 trainer board. Port C-upper of the 8255 programmable peripheral interface is set to output, and you bring low the row you want to scan, leaving the other two rows high. Port A is set to input, and from that you can read off which keys in that row are pressed (and possibly ghost keys if the correct combinations of keys in other rows are pressed).

The three 1SS53 diodes are small signal diodes, very much like a 1N4148. If I'm understanding this right, they allow the output port to pull row lines low, but prevent it from driving the row lines high, so that the row lines are floating when when not being actively pulled low.

What is the purpose of these three diodes?

[image: TK-85 keyboard circuit]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Oh, duh; of course I figure it out moments after I post the question.

The diodes prevent a high port C output from driving a low port C output, creating a short circuit between the two that would no doubt make the chip very unhappy.

If output PC4 is driven low and output PC5 is driven high, holding down the 0 key will bring the column and PA0 low which is fine, because there's a resistor R66 between the current source and the row and column.

However, if you hold down both the 0 and 8 keys, you will have shorted together the two rows. The diodes prevent any shorted rows that are connected to high output row select pins from driving unlimited current into the rows that are connected to ground via the low output row select pin.

Is this right?

Comment: I think you've got it. Don't forget to accept your own answer when the timeout (a few hours?) elapses.

Comment: Yes correct. No further explanation needed.

Comment: Sometimes that's how things work out. We're your [rubber duck](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging).

Comment: @DaveTweed Actually, my theory is that posting the question immediately beamed it out to the subconscious of all the EESE readers, and I then immediately picked up their thought waves about it to get the answer from them. :-P (Seriously, I'd wondered about this for _more than a day_ and discussed it with someone else, before finally posting the question here, and the answer came to me literally within minutes of clicking "Post.")